# time avg within a mysql database within a certain time period

Tags: mysql

so im trying to get time averages within a 20 minute period and add it from my main sql table to a secondary table the number will go into the database several time throughout the day and it works well the 1st time the number goes in but then if it goes in later in the day it will update the secondary table to a much higher avg e.g.

number 58 goes in at 12:08 am and then stops going in at 12:31am the avg will show 23 minutes if it then goes back into the table at 13:47pm and goes out at 14:13pm it will show 2 hours and 5 minute

im currently using

```
insert into test.time (beacon,location,date,time_avg,mac,time)
SELECT beacon,location,date, 
TIMEDIFF(max(`time`),min(`time`)) AS `time_avg`,mac,time
FROM test.test where time > now() - interval 30 minute
group by beacon
ORDER BY `time_avg` DESC
```

how can i query it so that it add a new line for half hour or so i did try to use an event where it only queried it every 30 minutes rather than after every update but i still ended up with the same issue, i have also tried insert ignore where mac is a unique value and replace into.

I have attached a picture of my table to give an idea of the data that is in it.

example data in a string for ease

```
insert into test ('location','beacon','mac','date','time') VALUES (YELLOW, 1,AC3422845D, 2018-01-10, 12:08:55);
```

[mysql table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yywq.png)

Comment: We cannot use images can you add your sample data as text to the question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly every beacon/location/mac/date has an unknown number of times , you wish to calculate the timediff for chunks of times that fall into 20 minute intervals and average these out by the number of chunks in the day(so far). When would you start AND end these 20 minute chunks (00:00 - 24:00?)

Comment: @P.Salmon yes so its a constant running system to the actual set time doesnt matter however what im trying to achieve is that it only group together and works out the difference between the time the number is 1st seen and the time the number is last seen in a 20-30 minute interval but it doesnt seem to do this and calculates it for as long as the system runs and the 1st time the number is seen in the day and the last

Comment: There are a number of things which look wrong in your query 1 - trying to insert 6 fields into a table where 5 are expected (location?) 2 - you are comparing time to datetime (now())) this will cause any time on any previous date to be included if in the last 30 minutes , group by may result in indeterminate location and date and will fail if only_full_group_by is set (and it is by default in newer versions of mysql).

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of things to look at and probably fix in your insert..select. If your aim is to have 1 record in your insert table per beacon,mac,date then an insert on duplicate key is probably what you want.For example

MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

```
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t
    -> (location varchar(20),beacon int, mac varchar(20),`date` date, `time` time);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (location,beacon,mac,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('YELLOW', 1,'AC3422845D', '2018-01-10', '11:00:44');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (location,beacon,mac,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('YELLOW', 1,'AC3422845D', '2018-01-11', '10:00:55');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (location,beacon,mac,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('YELLOW', 1,'AC3422845D', '2018-01-11', '11:00:55');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (location,beacon,mac,`date`,`time`) VALUES ('YELLOW', 1,'AC3422845D', '2018-01-11', '12:00:55');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t1
    -> (beacon int,location varchar(20), mac varchar(20),`date` date, maxtimetime  time, mintime time, obs int, now30 datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> alter table t1
    -> add unique key  t1k1 (beacon,mac,`date`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> #select * from t;
MariaDB [sandbox]> #select @now;
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> set @now = str_to_date('2018-01-10 11:15:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t1 (beacon ,mac ,`date`, maxtimetime, mintime, obs, now30)
    -> select *
    -> from
    -> (select t.beacon,t.mac,t.`date`, max(`time`) maxtime,min(`time`) mintime,count(*) obs,
    -> @now - interval 30 minute now30
    -> from t
    -> where `time`  between time(@now - interval 30 minute) and time(@now) and `date` = date(@now)
    -> group by t.beacon ,t.mac,t.`date`
    -> ) s
    -> on duplicate key
    -> update maxtimetime = s.maxtime, mintime = s.mintime, obs = s.obs, now30 = s.now30;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t1;
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
| beacon | location | mac        | date       | maxtimetime | mintime  | obs  | now30               |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
|      1 | NULL     | AC3422845D | 2018-01-10 | 11:00:44    | 11:00:44 |    1 | 2018-01-10 10:45:00 |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> set @now = str_to_date('2018-01-11 11:15:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t1 (beacon ,mac ,`date`, maxtimetime, mintime, obs, now30)
    -> select *
    -> from
    -> (select t.beacon,t.mac,t.`date`, max(`time`) maxtime,min(`time`) mintime,count(*) obs,
    -> @now - interval 30 minute now30
    -> from t
    -> where `time` between time(@now - interval 30 minute) and time(@now) and `date` = date(@now)
    -> group by t.beacon ,t.mac,t.`date`
    -> ) s
    -> on duplicate key
    -> update maxtimetime = s.maxtime, mintime = s.mintime, obs = s.obs, now30 = s.now30;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t1;
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
| beacon | location | mac        | date       | maxtimetime | mintime  | obs  | now30               |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
|      1 | NULL     | AC3422845D | 2018-01-10 | 11:00:44    | 11:00:44 |    1 | 2018-01-10 10:45:00 |
|      1 | NULL     | AC3422845D | 2018-01-11 | 11:00:55    | 11:00:55 |    1 | 2018-01-11 10:45:00 |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> set @now = str_to_date('2018-01-11 12:15:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t1 (beacon ,mac ,`date`, maxtimetime, mintime, obs, now30)
    -> select *
    -> from
    -> (select t.beacon,t.mac,t.`date`, max(`time`) maxtime,min(`time`) mintime,count(*) obs,
    -> @now - interval 30 minute now30
    -> from t
    -> where `time`  between time(@now - interval 30 minute) and time(@now) and `date` = date(@now)
    -> group by t.beacon ,t.mac,t.`date`
    -> ) s
    -> on duplicate key
    -> update maxtimetime = s.maxtime, mintime = s.mintime, obs = s.obs, now30 = s.now30;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t1;
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
| beacon | location | mac        | date       | maxtimetime | mintime  | obs  | now30               |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
|      1 | NULL     | AC3422845D | 2018-01-10 | 11:00:44    | 11:00:44 |    1 | 2018-01-10 10:45:00 |
|      1 | NULL     | AC3422845D | 2018-01-11 | 12:00:55    | 12:00:55 |    1 | 2018-01-11 11:45:00 |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```